# Django view function for navbar

Tags: python, django

I have my  page only for `navigation bar` and I include it in base page. Now I have `drop down` menu in that navigation bar and links I get from database(that links are my categories).

But how can I call my function in views without path, because I don't need to have path for navigation bar? And I need that view `function` to get data from database.

Comment: You have to state your problem more precisely. I have no idea what your problem is. Present at least code basis for test case with wanted outcome

Answer (score 0):

You can pass database data to your templates via context variables like so:

**models.py**

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```py
def my_view_function(request):

    ...
    
    context = {
        'categories' : Category.objects.all()
    } 

    return render(request, 'template.html', context=context)
```

**template.html**

```html
<div id='navbar'>
  {% for category in categories %}
    <div> {{ category.name }} </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```